# My registracion is not sending to firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a registation for my android app and i cant send the data email and password registation to fire base
Email/passwor is enable

```
public class RegistoScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    ProgressBar progressBar;
EditText editTextEmail,editTextPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registo_screen);
        editTextEmail =  findViewById(R.id.mail_editor);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.pass_editor);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        findViewById(R.id.butom_registo_reg).setOnClickListener(this);




    }
    private void registerUser(){
        String email=editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

if(email.isEmpty()){
    editTextEmail.setError("Email está vazio");
    editTextEmail.requestFocus();
    return;

}

if(password.isEmpty()){
  editTextPassword.setError("Password em falta");
  editTextPassword.requestFocus();
}

if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
    editTextEmail.setError("O email inserido não e valido");
    editTextEmail.requestFocus();
    return;
}

if(password.length()<6){
    editTextPassword.setError("O tamanho minimo da password é 6 caracters");
    editTextPassword.requestFocus();
    return;
}

progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Utilizador Criado com sucesso",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Algo erro na criacao da conta",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
});

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.butom_registo_reg:
        registerUser();

        break;

    case R.id.butom_voltar:
        startActivity(new Intent(this,LoginScreen.class));

        break;
```

this is the dependencis

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
```

i already try to change the firebase version but the registatcion never happends i realy hope that i can fi this.
Thank you very much in advice

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question to indicate the exact error message you are getting. Thanks.

Comment: i am not getting an error the email and password simply do not appear on firebase

Comment: OK. I would be making sure the code is checking for exceptions after it attempts to write out these values.

Comment: You have 2 toasts, 1 in the success flow and 1 in the error flow. Which one displays for you?

Answer (score 0):

have you enable the Sign-in Method tab by by email/password in your authentication firebase ? if not, you can't register to the firebase and data will not show in firebase database.
if not the problem of authentication, could you please tell us what the messages in your `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener`